# Can "whose" be replaced with "with the/a" in this sentence? Which sentence is better?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context, verb-forms, word-in-context, possessive-pronouns

> I wrote a simple Email whose goal was to inform friends and family about the party.

Can the "whose" in the sentence be replaced with "with a/the" to make the sentence like:

> I wrote a simple Email with the goal of informing friends and family about the party.

Is the second sentence better than the first, as "whose", no matter what, sounds wrong? I'm looking for a way to rewrite this, keeping the word "goal".

Comment: I would just cut that part out entirely: "I wrote a simple email to inform friends and family about the party."

Comment: @Laurel, yes, that's simpler, but I'm looking for a way with the word "goal".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use ***whose*** with "inanimate" referents such as emails. From [Merriam-Webster...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whose-used-for-inanimate-objects#:%7E:text=Which%20and%20that%2C%20the%20relative,beginning%20of%20a%20question%3A%20while%20%22)

> **Whose** is the possessive form of the relative pronoun **who**.
> **Which** and **that**, the relative pronouns used for animals and objects, lack a possessive form, so **whose** can be used for their possessive forms as well, as in *"the movie, whose name I can't remember."*

Comment: And, yes, it can be replaced with _with the goal of_.

Comment: But, 'Who?''s answer is always a living being, right? So, as it doesn't have a possessive form, and it sounds wrong for an inanimate object, why not change it to a sentence like the second one? "The avoidance of whose certainly works, but the fact is it is easier to borrow whose to convey possession for an inanimate object than to work around it.": yes, it's easier to use 'whose', but why not avoid it?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder: I don't know what you mean by "it sounds wrong for an inanimate object". There's absolutely nothing wrong with ***whose*** in the cited "email" example context. The only real restriction applies in the context of *questions* starting with ***whose***, as pointed out in my M-W link (we can't transform ***Which book's** pages are torn?* into ***Whose** pages are torn?*). In other contexts, there's nothing to be avoided.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the 'who' in 'whose'- as it can easily be rewritten in this case.

Comment: By pointing out that it *can* be rewritten, you imply that perhaps it *should* be rewritten (presumably because you're *still* not convinced it's okay to use ***whose*** of inanimate objects). But I don't really see why you asked a question about whether the usage is acceptable in the first place, if you don't want to be told that it's fine.